# Best practice for MySQL CASE with multiple WHEN conditions vs a single OR condition

Tags: mysql

Is there a *preferred* (or more performant) way of writing a `CASE` with multiple `WHEN` conditions that generate the same value?

For example:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN 1 > 0 AND 2 > 0 THEN 1
    WHEN 0 < 1 AND 0 < 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS multiple_WHEN,
  CASE
    WHEN (1 > 0 AND 2 > 0) OR (0 < 1 AND 0 < 2) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS single_OR
```

Would the remainder of the `WHEN` conditions need to be evaluated before reaching the end of the `CASE`, and would an `OR` condition act any differently?

Comment: Caution:  When you simplify a query for us, we will help you with the _simplified_ query.  The advice _may not_ apply to the _real_ query.

Comment: Perhaps a little oversimplified, but in my case I'm dealing with numerical comparisons.  I had read that considerations are needed when dealing with calculated values or parameters.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression seemed to provide a decent explanation but didn't quite cover what I was looking for

Comment: T-SQL and MySQL are different animals.  Advice about one may _or may not_ apply to the other.

Comment: Furthermore, some of the T-SQL syntax is not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance difference between the two suggestions is insignificant.

As a rule of thumb, *fetching* a row is far more costly than any expressions that need to be evaluated for that row.

Do whichever is easier for you.

The expressions in those examples will be evaluated before it starts to perform the query.  Perhaps your *real* query is more involved than that?  In particular, if `2 > 0` is, instead, some complex subquery, then I need to reconsider my answer.

These may apply to MySQL:

- "short circuit" -- But for simple expressions, you would be hard put to measure the performance difference.
- When possible `MATCH .. AGAINST` (`FULLTEXT`) is performed first.  (But this applies to `WHERE`, not `CASE`.)
- User functions can be defined as `DETERMINISTIC` or non.  This *should* impact the evaluation.  (But I don't have proof of such.)
- @variables are probably soon to be deprecated due to evaluation issues.